# Автопереход по ссылке после входа в одноклассники

Tags: android, webview

Я загружаю

```
      wv.loadUrl("https://m.ok.ru");
```

Я проверяю заголовок страницы

```
    @Override
    public void onReceivedTitle(WebView view, String sTitle, String url){
        if(sTitle.equals("Добро пожаловать в Одноклассники!")){ //если грузится страница входа
            drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED); //блокируем меню
        }else{
            if(sTitle.equals("Одноклассники")){ //а если вход в одноклассники выполнен 
                drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED); //разблокируем меню
                wv.loadUrl("https://m.ok.ru/app/nebo") //загружаем игру
            }
        }
        super.onReceivedTitle(view, sTitle);
    }
```

По идее, боковуха должна работать только если юзер вошел в акк. И моя "переадресация" тоже не происходит. Такое чувство что проверка на заголовок всегда дает `false`. Хотя они валидные. Заголовок страницы входа - Добро пожаловать в Одноклассники!, а возможные заголовки страниц после входа - "С чего начать?", " одноклассники". "Одноклассники". Мало того не работает автопереход, ещё и `Drawerlayout` не слушается...

**UPD:** Проверял и логами и тостами. Всегда возвращает false. Или я что-то не то с заголовком делаю? Как взять заголовок? И неужели разработчики приложений вот так вот всегда голову ломают? Мне кажется у меня костыль))

Comment: Я думаю, хардом сравнивать заголовок не самая лучшая идея. Просто потому что однажды заголовок может поменяться и как следствие, вам придется менять код в программе. Возможно, там где-то стоит пробел или `\n` невидимый, из-за этого и false возвращает. Вероятно, есть другие способы, которыми можно проверить какая страница сейчас открылась)

Comment: @whalemare, :( какие, например?

Comment: Не смогу пока ответить на этот вопрос.
Попробуйте вывести в лог строку, которая приходит вторым параметром в `onReceivedTitle` и посмотрите что выйдет. Там же можете сравнить.
http://pastebin.com/raw/MBV6qHeV

Comment: @whalemare, ничего в логах не добавляется :-(

Comment: @СергейГрушин, whalemare просит вас написать, что передается в метод в строке `url` ?

Comment: @miha_dev, не понял. url? У меня он просто объявляется. Никак не инициализируется. Но в методе     onPageStart  происходит LASTURL = url;

Comment: @СергейГрушин, у вас в заголовке метода `public void onReceivedTitle(WebView view, String sTitle, String url)` есть параметр url. Что в нем передается? можете вывести в лог `Log.d("TAG", "url = " +  url);`

Comment: @miha_dev, только сегодня начал изучать логи. Сейчас.

Comment: @miha_dev, вот мой код метода
        public void onReceivedTitle(WebView view, String titleText, String url)
  {
            super.onReceivedTitle(view, titleText);
   
  Log.d("TAG", "url = " + url); 
   }
   }
   ); в логе приоритета D ничего не выводится

Comment: @whalemare, как же сделать...

Comment: Вы разобрались с логами? У вас `Android Studio`?
Вот исчерпывающая статья по логам http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/19-urok-12-logi-i-vsplyvajuschie-soobschenija
Если не выводится ничего, то:
1. Метод не был вызван
2. Вы проглядели строчки в логах

Чтобы исключить 2 пункт: Вы отсортировали ваши логи? У меня все логи идут с тегом "WHALETAG", попробуйте придумать нечто похожее, снова выполните программу и отсортируйте по этому тегу все пришедшие логи. Вот так это делается: http://hkar.ru/GCjv

Comment: А, ну и конечно же
Последнюю строчку в методе: 
"super.onReceivedTitle(view, sTitle);" нужно выводить первой, поскольку идет обращение к суперклассу (родителю), а после должен выполняться Ваш код. Почитайте про это вот здесь: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/extends.php
Думаю, все должно заработать. Вот код, если непонятно объяснил:
http://pastebin.com/raw/bwmaMcnt

Comment: @СергейГрушин как успехи?

Comment: @whalemare, вставил, ничего не работает. Все, так же. Какой есть альтернативный способ? Делаю приложение в смартфоне. Приложение AIDE. Что если мне сделать проверку открытой страницы по ссылке? Или... Блиииин, мозги болят :(

Comment: @СергейГрушин по ссылке будет лучше, я думаю. 
Странно, что не работает. Если Вы сделали все что я сказал, то помочь больше ничем не смогу, к сожалению, т.к. ошибок не вижу.
и "ничего не работает" не совсем уместный ответ) Что именно не работает?

Comment: @whalemare, не работает автоматический вход в игру после входа на страничку